# MongoDB Error Code 16755 - Can't extract geo keys & duplicate vertices

Tags: mongodb, geometry, 2dsphere

When I try to create an index on geometry `db.polygons.createIndex({"geometry":"2dsphere"})`, it stops at a certain polygon with the error code 16755. It says it `Can't extract geo keys` and `Duplicate vertices: 18 and 20`.

So upon further inspection, it seems like this happens when 2 nodes in a polygon are close together, or even duplicates.

I then go manually remove this node in QGIS and re-try the process, only to find there's another polygon with the same issue.

How can I fix this issue without having to repeat the entire process of fixing polygon > uploading to MongoDB > creating index? Is there a way I can find out how many polygons have this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hit a similar problem. I just needed to find the valid records in my dataset (I discarded the records with Duplicate Vertices).

I renamed the collection -

```
db.myCollection.renameCollection('myCollectionBk')
```

Then I added a single record from the original collection into a new collection and added a geospatial index to the collection

```
db.myCollection.insert(db.myCollectionBk.findOne()) // recreate the collection
db.myCollection.createIndex({geometry:"2dsphere"}) // create the index (assumes the geometry on the record is valid)
db.myCollection.remove({}) // remove the record
```

Then I added the valid records into the new collection.

```
db.myCollectionBk.find().forEach(function(x){
    db.myCollection.insert(x);
})
```

Invalid records are simply ignored.

In your case you probably want to get the [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#writeresults-insert) from your [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/), and look to see if it was successful. Something like

```
var errors = []
db.myCollectionBk.find().forEach(function(x){
    var result = db.myCollection.insert(x);
    if (result.writeError) {
        errors.push({x._id:result.writeError.errmsg});
    }
})
```

As another alternative, check out [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43961/how-to-remove-duplicate-point-features) (I couldn't get this to work)

Comment: Brilliant. I was about to go down a dark dark path. I wonder if there's a way to do this in a more bulk like fashion.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day ! :D

Answer (score 1):

So what I did was, I first created the collection with the index and then tried inserting using mongoimport which gave me how many were inserted successfully.

```
> db.someNewCollection.createIndex({"geometry":"2dsphere"})
```

To insert GeoJSON into MongoDB I did the following:

```
$ jq --compact-output ".features" yourGeoJSON > output.geojson
$ mongoimport --db someDB -c someNewCollection --file "output.geojson" --jsonArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same problem,
Quick fix : Just delete your index you created for storing coordinates and then create again.It will get created again with empty state,
Reason : this error occured because it somehow got the duplicate values in its index and its not able to resolve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).